# Replace bars by line break in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want replace '/' by a line break in javascript.

I have this string:

```
L-V:DE 08:30 A 14:30 Y DE 16:30 A 20:00/S:DE 09:30 A 13:00/Festivos:SIN SERVICIO
```

I want to turn it into:

```
L-V:DE 08:30 A 14:30 Y DE 16:30 A 20:00
S:DE 09:30 A 13:00
Festivos:SIN SERVICIO
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `string.replace`

replace take

- a pattern string (you could use regex pattern)
- a string to replace the match

example:

```js
< "hello/i/m/here".replace(/\//g, "\n")
> "hello
i
m
here"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split it with your separator (/) and then join it using new line character (\n).

```js
console.log('L-V:DE 08:30 A 14:30 Y DE 16:30 A 20:00/S:DE 09:30 A 13:00/Festivos:SIN SERVICIO'.split('/').join('\n'));
```